# php search by first letter

Tags: php

I have a search section in my web page. I used the following code to search the board member names.

```
$select_board="SELECT * FROM `tbl_boardmembers` WHERE `varBoardmembername` LIKE '%$find%'";
```

I need to change my code to search by using just the first letter. I tried this code

```
$select_board="SELECT * FROM `tbl_boardmembers` WHERE `varBoardmembername` LIKE '" . $letter . "%'";
```

But it doesn't works. How can i do that?

Comment: do you get any error-messages or -codes? can you give more information about what doesn't work? is it a sql-error, a syntax-error or do you just don't get the rows you're expecting to get? how are `$find` and/or `$letter` initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **"Search by first letter of $find"**

```
var $letter = substr( $find, 0, 1 );

$select_board="SELECT * FROM `tbl_boardmembers` WHERE `varBoardmembername` LIKE '" . $letter . "%'";
```

Comment: you can use direct char "array" access rather than `substr`, e.g. `$letter = $find{0}`;